# What's different about a directory based cache coherence protocol?

Tags: multithreading, caching

I understand a general cache-coherence protocol is to maintain consistency between multiple local copies (caches) of shared data.

What I don't understand is what it means to be a directory-based cache coherence protocol?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In simplified terms, a [directory based cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory-based_cache_coherence) coherence system means that cache coherence management is **centrelized**, meaning it is managed by a single unit - the directory.

The directory holds the state for all memory blocks and manages request for these blocks from the nodes (processors). For instance, if a node would like read a block into its cache, it must ask permission from the directory. The directory then checks to see if any other nodes hold the block and forces them to update it if necessary.